# Screen cant find file on ArchLinux

Tags: linux, shell, archlinux, gnu-screen

On my ArchLinux server, I run Screen for background jobs.

When I run screen `build.sh`, I get the following error message:

`- Cannot exec 'build.sh': No such file or directory.`

I changed my script on my computer, then copied it to the server and replaced the old file. Then I did:  `chmod u+x build.sh`

It is located in `/usr/local/bin`, which is added to the `$PATH` variable.

I have also ran `pacman -Syu`

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a solution. As I changed the file on Windows I had to run the following in vim.

```
:set ff=unix
:set nobomb
:wq
```

Found the solution here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27054/bin-bash-no-such-file-or-directory